# Can we perform multiple transformations on an element through different animations?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transforms

In CSS to apply multiple transformations to the same element in one rule it must be written like this: 
`.selector{ transform:translateY( *value* ) scale( *value*) rotateZ(*value*)` etc. But how do I add multiple transformations in multiple animations? Example:

```css
@import 'https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css';
/* //////////////////////////////// INITIAL //////////////////////////////// */
html, body{ height:100% } body{ background:#eee }
#btnCont{
  display:block; width:100px; height:100px; margin:0 auto; position:relative;
  transform:translateY(-50%); top:50%; perspective:1000px
}
#btn {
  width:100%; height:100%; background:#333; color:#eee; border:0; outline:0;
  text-transform:uppercase; transform:rotateX(93deg) translateX(0);
  transform-origin:bottom
}
/* //////////////////////////////// __ANIM_ //////////////////////////////// */
.rotUp{ 
  animation-name:rotateUp; animation-duration:1s; animation-fill-mode:forwards 
}
.movUp{
  animation-name:moveUp; animation-duration:1.5s; animation-fill-mode:forwards
}
@keyframes rotateUp{ 
  0%{ transform:rotateX(93deg) }
  100%{ transform:rotateX(0deg)  }
}
@keyframes moveUp{ 
  0%{ transform:translateX(0) }
  100%{ transform:translateX(95px)  }
}
```

```html
<div id="btnCont"> <button id="btn" class="rotUp movUp">button</button> </div>
```

I want to perform `rotateUp` and `moveUp` simultaneously. As it is now, `rotateUp` gets completely ignored.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I animate multiple css transform properties separately using keyframe animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579730/can-i-animate-multiple-css-transform-properties-separately-using-keyframe-animat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transform can take more than one rule/value at once. you can mix those values and add as many steps as you wish.

Basicly:

```css
@import 'https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css';
/* //////////////////////////////// INITIAL //////////////////////////////// */
html, body{ height:100% } body{ background:#eee }
#btnCont{
  display:block; width:100px; height:100px; margin:0 auto; position:relative;
  transform:translateY(-50%); top:50%; perspective:1000px
}
#btn {
  width:100%; height:100%; background:#333; color:#eee; border:0; outline:0;
  text-transform:uppercase; transform:rotateX(93deg) translateX(0);
  transform-origin:bottom
}
/* //////////////////////////////// __ANIM_ //////////////////////////////// */
.rotUp.movUp{
  animation-name:anim; animation-duration:1.5s; animation-fill-mode:forwards
}
@keyframes anim{ 
  0%{ transform:rotateX(93deg) translateX(0) }
  75%{ transform:rotateX(25deg)  translateX(90px) }
  100%{ transform:rotateX(0deg)  translateX(95px) }
}
```

```html
<div id="btnCont"> <button id="btn" class="rotUp movUp">button</button> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Animations are essentially applying styles to elements, in the way JS applies styles directly to the node.

So when you apply a single animation, it overwrites your stylesheet in the same way that applying a style directly to the element with the style attribute takes precedence over a stylesheet.

When you apply two animations, the second overwrites the first, because you can only have one winning style definition. This is also why you don't get both an X and Y transform when you define an animation like

```
@keyframes changeStuff{ 
  0%{ transform:rotateX(90deg) }
  100%{ transform:rotateY(90deg)  }
}
```

(the transform at 100% overwrites the transform at 0%).

So the solution to your problem is to write a single animation for `.rotUp.movUp`.