# JS: How to save chained animations as a variable to play, pause, etc

Tags: javascript, html, web-animations

If i want to control a simple animation, I can set it to `header` variable and then do `header.play()` like this:

```
  let header= element.animate({
      transform: ['scale(1)', 'scale(1.5)']
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      fill: 'both'
    });
  
  header.play();
```

but when I chain it so that different animations happen together using `composite`, that won't work since it's multiple definitions:

```
element.animate({
  transform: ['scale(1)', 'scale(1.5)']
}, {
  duration: 1000,
  fill: 'both'
});

element.animate({
  transform: ['rotate(0deg)', 'rotate(180deg)']
}, {
  duration: 1500,
  fill: 'both',
  composite: 'add'
});
```

how would I control these together to make use of `play()`, `pause()` ?

Comment: Are you using an animation library? You should probably tell us which one.

Comment: no, standard web animation API in javascript

Comment: when you say "happen together" what do you mean? that is ambiguous. please describe exactly the behavior. is it in sequence, or at the same time?

Comment: @r3wt using the `composite` property, I am adding to the `transform` property in the 2nd animation rather than replacing the scale with the rotate.  So scale _and_ rotate will happen at the same time

Comment: do you have a codepen @RicardoAlvveroa I haven't used this api before but if you throw up an example i'll attempt to help you.

Comment: sure: https://jsfiddle.net/m8or70xk/  .  As you can see, the box executes _both_ animations.  It applies both transforms at the same time but I am not sure how to put that in a variable to make access of `play()` again to trigger it at a later time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either chain two separate animations using DOM events (or even promises):

```
const firstPart = element.animate({
  transform: ['scale(1)', 'scale(1.5)']
}, {
  duration: 1000,
  fill: 'both'
});

firstPart.finished.then(() => {
  const secondPart = element.animate({
    transform: ['rotate(0deg)', 'rotate(180deg)']
  }, {
    duration: 1500,
    fill: 'both'
  });
  return secondPart.finished;
});
```

Or you can create a single animation with multiple keyframes:

```
element.animate([
  { offset: 0, transform: 'scale(1)' },
  { offset: .6, transform: 'scale(1.5) rotate(0deg)' }
  { offset: 1, transform: 'scale(1.5) rotate(180deg)' }
], {
  duration: 2500,
  fill: 'both',
  composite: 'add'
});
```

The keyframes solution also allows animating both properties at the same time if you want. However, [animating two `transform`s indepdently is a bit complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13580112/1048572).

Comment: thanks @bergi.  Wouldn't this sequentially run them though?  Like wait for the `firstPart` to execute and finish, then run the 2nd?

Comment: @RicardoAlvveroa Didn't you say you wanted to chain them?

Comment: so that they fire together....perhaps chaining wasn't the right word. sorry.  But they start at the same time, one having the duration of 1000 and another having 1500 duration but both doing different transforms, hence the need for the `composite: add`

Comment: @RicardoAlvveroa Ah I see. How would you expect them to repeat (if they were repeating)?

Comment: as if I executed those 2 `animate()`s at the same time again , if that makes sense

Comment: So you want the scaling to wait 500ms after it's finished before starting again? Then you can use a single animation with the respective keyframes

Comment: got it, ok.  Sorry for the runaround.  I never used `composite` before.

Comment: Note that as of the latest Safari TP, all the major browser engines support the individual transform properties so in future animating scale and rotate independently should become much easier: https://webkit.org/blog/11420/css-individual-transform-properties/

Comment: @brianskold Oh, nice!